# Ubuntu in virtual box is very small, and does not maximize

Tags: virtualbox

I installed virtual box in my mac and installed ubuntu. I thought it would run without problem but the after installing it the size of the virtual machine is very small. Unusable. I tried to resize it but it does not work. (the window resize but not ubuntu)

I applied [this method](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=177&v=RxmGFsaOyks&feature=emb_logo) to resize it and now I can resize it to some extent but very clumsily. And when I try the full screen I just get a black screen

How can this problem be solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you already have installed the VirtualBox Guest Additions you are also able to change screen resolution and use drag/drop and copy/paste from host to guest and vice versa. 
To avoid the guest getting freezed with bigger resolutions, you should increase the resources in VirtualBox settings for this guest.

Shut down Ubuntu guest and increase in VirtualBox settings of VM:

1) <kbd>Display</kbd> | <kbd>Screen</kbd> | <kbd>Video Memory</kbd> (try the maximum)

2) <kbd>System</kbd> | <kbd>Motherboard</kbd> | <kbd>Base Memory</kbd> (try half of maximum)

Comment: Thanks. I am still checking but it seems this works. Now the full screen is not black. The only thing is that now the things are pretty small so I am going to change too this: Display->Screen->Scale Factor and try

Comment: I am writing this from the virtual machine. The fonts are still really small but somehow workable. Using ubuntu from the virtual machine feels a bit clumsy yet.

Comment: @KansaiRobot, you should try also **Settings | Universal Access** and then activate **Large Text** and change maybe the **Cursor Size**. In Ubuntu 20.04 (as of today still beta), you'll find **Fractional Scaling** in **Settings | Universal Access**, which allows you a finer granular scaling factor. If my answer helped you, pleas upvote...

Comment: I was looking for those options in the VM, then I got that they were ubuntu settings. I set the Large Text and it really helped! thanks!

Comment: You are right, I should have mention that these settings are in Ubuntu. However, I'm glad it worked for you.